# R tcltk: How to add buttons in array

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

This code will produce 50 buttons. I would like to put them in an array so I can reference them later and change their attribute based on some condition. My code is as follows:

```
numIDs = 50;
bs = array (0, c(numIDs));
for (num in 1:numIDs)
{
    b <- tkbutton (f.frame);
    print (paste (length(b[num]), length(b)));
    bs[num] <- b;
    tkpack (bs[num]);
}
```

The above code produces the error:

```
In bs[num] <- b :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Execution halted
```

The `print` in the loop produces `[1] "1 2"` so the lengths are different and that is why the assignment fails but how do I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a `list`, not an `array`:

```
f.frame <- tktoplevel() # just for reproducibility

numIDs = 50;
bs = list();
for (num in 1:numIDs) {
    b <- tkbutton (f.frame);
    print (paste (length(b[num]), length(b)));
    bs[[num]] <- b; # note `[[` extraction for lists
    tkpack (bs[[num]]); # note `[[` extraction for lists
}
```